# AgglomerativeClustering with disconnected connectivity constraint

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have tried this both on the latest 0.16.1 version and on the latest bleeding edge version of sklearn '0.17.dev0' and this appears to be an issue in both.

I use

```
sklearn.cluster.AgglomerativeClustering(affinity='precomputed',connectivity=Cmat,linkage='complete')
```

where Cmat is a connectivity matrix in which there are disconnected components. 
As indicated by the source code, I get the error message UserWarning: the number of connected components of the connectivity matrix is *>1. Completing it to avoid stopping the tree early.

However, reading the source code I see that when completing the connectivity matrix the developers are wondering whether the clustering can take place without completing the matrix:
""XXX: Can we do without completing the matrix?""

I am interested exactly in this development. Do you think sklearn is planning to fix this and make it possible to do the clustering without completing the matrix? Has anyone implemented it themselves? I would gladly take advise on this!

Comment: `Do you think sklearn is planning to fix this and make it possible to do the clustering without completing the matrix?` - We cannot really answer that. There's a scikit-learn channel on gitter, where also some of the devs are hanging around. You may get an answer there.

Comment: For anyone interested, I figured out to avoid this problem. If you use a distance matrix as input the way I do, and it is for values between 0 and 1. Just add a distance value of 1 between all corresponding disconnected components. I checked the source code, and the way it completes the connectivity matrix is by considering the minimum distance between disconnected components. In this way, by adding a distance of 1 (or any other maximum distance) you force the connectivity matrix to be completed in a more natural way rather than by merging disconnected components.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Check out [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) in the help center, and consider writing your comment up as an actual answer.

Comment: Does anyone has anything new on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested, I figured out to avoid this problem. If you use a distance matrix as input the way I do, and it is for values between 0 and 1. Just add a distance value of 1 between all corresponding disconnected components. I checked the source code, and the way it completes the connectivity matrix is by considering the minimum distance between disconnected components. In this way, by adding the highest possible distance of 1 (or any other maximum distance) you force the connectivity matrix to be completed in a more natural way rather than by merging disconnected components.